# Strange String.Format() - Input string was not in a correct format case

Tags: c#, string, string.format

I can't seem to understand why I'm running into trouble as I've done this several times but with this string to be formatted `string fsql = string.Format(sql, fa);` I get the error: `Input string was not in a correct format case`.

`sql`:

```
"DECLARE @BENTEST varchar(100)\r\nSET @BENTEST = '{1}'\r\n\r\nSELECT a.Period, a.NCR, a.Date_Created, a.Date_Done, a.Item, a.Qty, tc.TargetCost*a.Qty Cost, a.Aging FROM\r\n\t(SELECT \r\n\tnt.NCR, \r\n\tDATENAME(yy, nt.Date_Done) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(ISOWK, nt.Date_Done), 2) Period,\r\n\tnt1.Date_Created,\r\n\tnt.Date_Done,\r\n\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%\"%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedItem FROM\r\n\t\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%\"Item%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('\"Item\":\"'), 60) FirstParseStep) a) Item,\r\n\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM\r\n\t\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%\"ItemQty%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('\"ItemQty\":'), 60) FirstParseStep) a ) Qty,\r\n\tPCF.dbo.GetRealWorkDays(nt1.Date_Created, nt.Date_Done) Aging\r\n\tFROM PCF.dbo.NCRTask nt, PCF.dbo.NCRTask nt1\r\n\tWHERE nt1.NCR = nt.NCR\r\n\tAND (nt.TaskType = 5 OR nt.TaskType = 16)\r\n\tAND nt1.TaskType = 25\r\n\tUNION\r\n\tSELECT \r\n\tnt.NCR, \r\n\tDATENAME(yy, @BENTEST) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(ISOWK, @BENTEST), 2) Period,\r\n\tnt.Date_Created,\r\n\tnull Date_Done,\r\n\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%\"%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedItem FROM\r\n\t\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%\"Item%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('\"Item\":\"'), 60) FirstParseStep) a) Item,\r\n\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM\r\n\t\t(SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%\"ItemQty%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('\"ItemQty\":'), 60) FirstParseStep) a ) Qty,\r\n\tPCF.dbo.GetRealWorkDays(nt.Date_Created, GETDATE()) Aging\r\n\tFROM PCF.dbo.NCRTask nt\r\n\tWHERE nt.TaskType = 25\r\n\tAND nt.Date_Created < @BENTEST\r\n\tAND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PCF.dbo.NCRTask WHERE nt.NCR = NCR AND (TaskType = 5 OR TaskType = 16) AND Date_Done < @BENTEST)) a,\r\n\tavvik1.dbo.TargetCost tc\r\nWHERE a.Period = DATENAME(yy, @BENTEST) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(ISOWK, @BENTEST), 2)\r\nAND tc.ItemNo = a.Item"
```

`sql` but formatted so you can easily read it:

```
DECLARE @BENTEST varchar(100)
SET @BENTEST = '{1}'

SELECT a.Period, a.NCR, a.Date_Created, a.Date_Done, a.Item, a.Qty, tc.TargetCost*a.Qty Cost, a.Aging FROM
    (SELECT 
    nt.NCR, 
    DATENAME(yy, nt.Date_Done) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(ISOWK, nt.Date_Done), 2) Period,
    nt1.Date_Created,
    nt.Date_Done,
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%"%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedItem FROM
        (SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%"Item%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('"Item":"'), 60) FirstParseStep) a) Item,
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM
        (SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%"ItemQty%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('"ItemQty":'), 60) FirstParseStep) a ) Qty,
    PCF.dbo.GetRealWorkDays(nt1.Date_Created, nt.Date_Done) Aging
    FROM PCF.dbo.NCRTask nt, PCF.dbo.NCRTask nt1
    WHERE nt1.NCR = nt.NCR
    AND (nt.TaskType = 5 OR nt.TaskType = 16)
    AND nt1.TaskType = 25
    UNION
    SELECT 
    nt.NCR, 
    DATENAME(yy, @BENTEST) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(ISOWK, @BENTEST), 2) Period,
    nt.Date_Created,
    null Date_Done,
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%"%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedItem FROM
        (SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%"Item%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('"Item":"'), 60) FirstParseStep) a) Item,
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM
        (SELECT SUBSTRING(nt.ItemData, PATINDEX('%"ItemQty%', nt.ItemData) + LEN('"ItemQty":'), 60) FirstParseStep) a ) Qty,
    PCF.dbo.GetRealWorkDays(nt.Date_Created, GETDATE()) Aging
    FROM PCF.dbo.NCRTask nt
    WHERE nt.TaskType = 25
    AND nt.Date_Created < @BENTEST
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PCF.dbo.NCRTask WHERE nt.NCR = NCR AND (TaskType = 5 OR TaskType = 16) AND Date_Done < @BENTEST)) a,
    avvik1.dbo.TargetCost tc
WHERE a.Period = DATENAME(yy, @BENTEST) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(ISOWK, @BENTEST), 2)
AND tc.ItemNo = a.Item
```

`fa` is a string[] and it consist of:

```
[0] = ""
[1] = date with format "YYYY-MM-DD"
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting the error. I've done it for some other sql:s and I'm not having this issue. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Can we see your C# code as well?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Don't use `string.Format()` to put parameter values into your SQL.

Comment: @JLRishe why not? Sql differs each time I can't concat string when the sql is set dynamically.

Comment: Instead `DECLARE @BENTEST varchar(100)\r\nSET @BENTEST = '{1} ...` start with `{0}` like in ` `DECLARE @BENTEST varchar(100)\r\nSET @BENTEST = '{0} ...`. However, you also have to fix that lonely `}` in the middle of the sql string-. I would use a stored-procedure instead. Then you can pass arguments via sql-parameter.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter should'nt [0] be ignored in fa because there is no {0} in the sql-string?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho No, from what I can see, the SQL is the same each time. It's just that one value that's different. So use [parameterized SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx) for goodness' sake.

Comment: Or for [Bobby Tables'](http://bobby-tables.com) sake.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho: it's not `[0]` but `{1}` and that is not ignored. The message is "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

Comment: @TimSchmelter There's no problem with passing two parameter values and only using `{1}`. The `0`th item will simply be ignored, as OP says.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, string.Format will omit each argument in params list if there is no appropriate placeholder in format string.

Comment: @JLRishe yes using String.Format is dumb considering you can sql inject but why does the current code generate an error? I've tried declaring BENTEST as datetime and varchar but both gives the same error.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho I don't know. It's a gigantic string and presumably `string.Format` doesn't like something in it. It's not intended for inputs like this. **Edit:** PetSerAl has the answer.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: sure? `string.Format("{1}", "test"); ` boom

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, that's not analogous. What OP is doing is equivalent to `string.Format("{1}", "test", "test2");`.

Comment: @JLRishe: i'm fairly sure that OP's array contains one string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I quote: "_`fa` is a `string[]` and it consist of:
`[0] = ""`
`[1] = date with format "YYYY-MM-DD"`_". And the issue you're describing would not produce the error that OP is getting.

Comment: @JLRishe: thanks, i've overlooked that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have non escaped `}` in your string:

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM
                                                  ^
```

You should escape it:

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you just put the 2 variables in the string.Format, however you never set a string or told it to use the variables. perhaps you meant to do something like this? :

```
string fsql = string.Format("{0} {1}":sql, fa);
```

since you have to give up a string and you can use the {} with the index of the variable given behind the string instead of just declaring the strings. for more information of String.Format please refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't use that. The string to be formatted could be infinite variables to be replace. Then fa should also be infinite long.

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(a.FirstParseStep, 0, PATINDEX('%}}%', a.FirstParseStep)) ParsedQuantity FROM
```